# Can OpenGraph "description" fields contain HTML?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When sharing via a service implementing OpenGraph, like Facebook, can I include HTML in the `og:description` field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. It is a text string.

http://ogp.me/#string

Comment: It is, but it will be rendered as `<b>Hi</b>` to the viewer

Comment: That is unfortunately only implied by ogp.me - "A one to two sentence description of your object" :(